# crystal report: Manage serial number excluding duplicate rows

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report which was displaying duplicate row like below :

```
 SR  Particula    Remark  
 1. HD      500 GB  
 2. HD      500 GB  
 3. HD       500GB  
 4. RAM      2 GB  
 5. RAM      2 GB  
 6. RAM      2 GB  
 7. Charger  655244324  
 8. Charger  655244324  
 9. Charger  655244324
```

then i exclude duplicate records using following formula

```
{item.particular}=previous({item.particula})
```

and got following result :

```
SR  Particula   Remark  

 1. HD         500 GB
 4. RAM        2 GB
 7. Charger    655244324
```

> SR is unbound field

how to keep serial number in sequence?

Comment: Is SR is coming from database?

Comment: No, its Formula field from field explorer

Comment: what is the code in that formula?

Comment: whileprintingrecords;
numbervar var;
var := var+1;
var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways you can deal with the problem:

1. Check the option `Select Distinct Records` in `Database Tab` which will only take 3 records instead of 9 records.
2. You can use `Running Total` for calculation `SR`

While creating running total increment SR on change of `Remark` and reset never.

Let me know how it goes

Comment: I have distinct records in database and i get correct result in DataGridView but in crystal report it display duplicate records

Comment: The try second option that is `running total`

Comment: Thanx...., "While creating running total increment SR on change of Remark and reset never." work for me